# testing for array membership in JS produces surprising results

Tags: javascript, arrays, membership

I have the following lines of JS in a program...

```
            console.log(self.dataset[altAspect][altGroup] + " is the contents of the altGroup");
            console.log(answer + " is the answer to be checked");
            console.log('it is ' + (self.dataset[altAspect][altGroup].indexOf(answer) > -1) + ' that ' + answer + ' is a member of ' + self.dataset[altAspect][altGroup]);
            if (!self.dataset[altAspect][altGroup].indexOf(answer) > -1){                        
                self.wrongGroups.push(altGroup);
                console.log('added ' + altGroup + ' to the wrong groups!');
                self.altCount++;
            }
```

this logs the following to the console:

```
ginger,daisy is the contents of the altGroup  app.js:203:21
daisy is the answer to be checked  app.js:204:21
it is false that daisy is a member of ginger,daisy  app.js:205:21
added skinny to the wrong groups!  app.js:208:25
```

My question is, why is the above saying that "daisy" is not a member of ["ginger", "daisy"]?  Obviously when I run `[ "ginger", "daisy" ].indexOf("daisy")` I should get `1` in return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use `[ "ginger", "daisy" ].indexOf("daisy")` you got 1 as index value and

if you use this      `[ "ginger", "daisy" ].indexOf(answer)` you getting -1 as index value..

so, it may arises due to some whitespace may occur in your variable `answer`

you try to compare length of both...

compare `answer.length` with `"daisy".length` or else try this,

`[ "ginger", "daisy" ].indexOf(answer.trim())` . probably you will notice issue while getting text length..